# Input/output Java Android

Tags: java, android, io

How can I create a file(using Java for Android) in my Application data directory and write an integer in it and then use that integer?
I think I would save it in `.txt` or `.xml` file.

Comment: If you only need to save an integer, why would you write it to a file instead of using [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)?

Comment: what have you tried so far and what didn't work? If you haven't try anything yet, what's wrong with the ~zillion resources on the subject offered by google/android dev website?

Comment: +1 for Tanis. This seems like a very strange request.

Comment: Here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376807/how-to-read-write-string-from-a-file-in-android

Comment: Tanis I think it is useful but i would create a file and than use SharedPreferences?

Comment: If you use `SharedPreferences`, you don't need to worry about file IO at all. The framework will take care of the details of how and where the data is saved.

Comment: ooh) thanks i would try it

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to save the file to 'internal' memory (making the file only accessible to the app), then do the following:

```
 OutputStreamWriter outputWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("somefile.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
 String fileContent = "<xml>xmlstuff</xml>";
 outputWriter.write(fileContent);
 outputWriter.close();
```

Comment: but how can I create that somefile.xml?

Comment: that _is_ how you create somefile.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can use the methods `openFileOutput`, and `openFileInput` from the context, you should have access to this methods through your Activity.

You can check it on bellow link
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput(java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput%28java.lang.String%29)