# Android Information Write to File

Tags: java, android, file-io, camera, android-camera

I am writing an Android application, and I'd like to check my camera's supported focus modes. I got the List of supported focus modes.

So far, I've used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376807/how-to-read-write-string-from-a-file-in-android) question to write to a file. However, I cannot find where this file is located on the device. Is there a better way to write a List to a file?

I've seen some questions saying to use the Emulator in Eclipse, however the device I am using is not a standard Android phone and I cannot use an emulator. However, I have a file explorer and I can view files across the whole device.

Answer (score 0):

The link you are refering to is utilizing methods openFileInput() and openFileOutput(). See link [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput(java.lang.String)). The files created this way are private to your app so you cannot see them via file explorer. However in rooted devices they can be viewed.

Comment: My device is rooted. Is there another way I should be writing?