# How to use of pointer and text file in android?

Tags: android, pointers, text, file-io

I want to read a text file in android application but I don't know!
Please help me to can read and write in a text file. And I want to use pointer in my code, but I don't know that how are syntax and steps for this.
Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376807/how-to-read-write-string-from-a-file-in-android/14377185#14377185

Comment: Hi.Thanks @R9J for text file.but pointer!!!,What i do?

Comment: what do u want to do with pointers?? Java has no pointers!!

Comment: No way for use reference in java?

Comment: There is a way to access object reference and no way to access memory reference.. what is it you are asking for?

Comment: Ok,thanks, but your answer about text file in above link :

Comment: openFileOutput and openFileInput methods?

Comment: how to access them? eclips not found these methods

Comment: If your class does not extends `Activity`, then use `context.openFileInput()` and `context.openFileOutput()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to access object reference and no way to access memory reference
 and if your class does not extends Activity, then use

```
context.openFileInput()
```

and

```
context.openFileOutput()
```