# Write in a CSV file situated in res/raw in android

Tags: android, csv

I'm trying to write in a CSV file situated in my res/raw resources. 
I can read it using

```
InputStream csvFile = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.fichier_csv);
```

But I don't know how to write in it because this method return an InputStream.

Comment: Files in res/raw are read only.

Comment: More specifically, *contents* of res/raw are read only.  By the time the app gets to the device they aren't even literal "files" any more.

Answer (score 1):

you cant write to raw, you need to create a new file in code and read/write to that

[How To Read/Write String From A File In Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376807/how-to-read-write-string-from-a-file-in-android)

Comment: Technically, this is an SO compliant answer as the fact that what the poster wants to do is not supported is a self-contained response to the question.  The link is arguably only supporting material to provide an alternative.