# To read a file from one gaming application(in C++) to my android app

Tags: java, android, c++, unity-game-engine, android-api-levels

I want to read a text file present in a different directory i.e Games Directory(/sdcard/Android/data/game_package_name/files) from my android app.

Is there any way to do so, if yes then please suggest.

Note: This is for production level application, so please avoid any root-specific features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you [cannot access another application's sandbox](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html).
However, if you can modify the other application, you can use a [ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) or similar sharing solution to provide access to this specific file from other applications.

### Store the shared file in a shared folder

As you want to access the file from different applications and the sandbox from one will not be available from the other, you should write your file in a directory accessible from both, for example:

```
String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "myFolderForBothApplications/myFileNameForBothApplications.txt";
```

### Use a Content Provider

If you prefer to keep your file as part of one application, you can still expose the information via a ContentProvider.
In it, override the [`public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#openFile%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%29) method, and in the other application, just use the method [`getContentResolver().openInputStream(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#openFile%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%29).

And here a few links to related topics where I shamelessly copied/pasted code from:

- [how to allow another app to access my app's data directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215622/how-to-allow-another-app-to-access-my-apps-data-directory)
- [How to access /data folder of another application through your application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34771313/how-to-access-data-folder-of-another-application-through-your-application)