# Cannot read/write/delete file through Android app

Tags: java, android, root, su

I am doing this through an app I am coding.

I copy a file from **/persist/** to the internal storage of my app using SU "**cpy**" and then I "**chmod**" it to **600** or even **777**. I get "**Access denied**" exception whenever I read that file. I can read any other file I create. I also changed the owner and group from "**root**" to **my app**, but I can still not touch that file - delete, read, write all fail.

Comment: read this question...........http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376807/how-to-read-write-string-from-a-file-in-android

Comment: @ExceptionLover I can read any other file that I have created in the same directory from the app, but not this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to **chcon** the file as well. Thanks to ChainFire!