# Access the file from internal storage from specified location

Tags: android

I have a file in my internal storage, like `folderOne/folderTwo/textfile.txt`
How can I access this file programmatically?

Comment: access? you want to read it's content? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376807/how-to-read-write-string-from-a-file-in-android?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

String yourFilePath = context.getFilesDir() + "folderOne /folderTwo/" + "textfile.txt";

File yourFile = new File( yourFilePath );

You want something like this?

Comment: yes I tried this way only but I am not able to read the file it is force closing the app

Comment: You have added read permission? Make sure you have added  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />  permission to read external storage in your manifest file.

Comment: yes added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Read permissions should be there not write permissions

Comment: still showing same problem. I am passing the address like

Comment: still I am facing same problem.

Comment: I am accessing the file like FileInputStream fis=openFileInput("/storage/emulated/0/folderone/foldertwo/textfile.txt");

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />