# Writing huge json object to file

Tags: java, android, json, memory

So i have a huge JSONObject that I need to write to a file, right now my code work perfectly on 90% of the devices, the problem is on low memory devices such as Amazon Fire TV the app crashes with an error "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError".
I wonder is there another more memory friendly way to write that json object to file?

That's my code:

```
    try{
        Writer output = null;
        if(jsonFile.isDirectory()){
            jsonFile.delete();
        }
        if(!jsonFile.exists()){
            jsonFile.createNewFile();
        }
        output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(jsonFile));
        output.write(mainObject.toString());
        output.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Use a streaming JSON option, such as `JsonWriter`.

Comment: for avoiding OOM, using largeHeap is an option, but not recommended though.

Comment: Already using largeHeap... @DarShan

Comment: Check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40168601/android-how-to-save-json-data-in-a-file-and-retrieve-it/40168829