# Working with ByteArrays and SecretKeySpec in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, aes, encryption-symmetric

I have a seemingly simple task..

Take a file, open it, take the byte stream as a AES key, and instantiate a `javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec` within Android Kotlin

```
if (key == null) {

  val my_bytes: ByteArray = byteArrayOf(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) 
  val algo = "AES"

  val secretKey = SecretKeySpec(my_bytes, algo)

  saveSecretKey(sharedPref, secretKey!!)
  return secretKey
}
```

Edit: `SecretKeySpec()` works now.  I just need to know how to put the bytes from the file into the android app properly.  Is hard coding in the app insecure?  Should I store the key as a file and read it in from the android file system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store the key as a file on the external drive the following things will happen:

1. You will need permission from the user to read/write to the external drive
2. Because the key is on the external drive it is susceptible to:
   2.1 Being deleted by the user
   2.2 Being read by an app/person other than the one you intended it for

Since secret key is symmetric, and can be used for both encryption and decryption.

Now, for our birds:

To load the file from the disk: [This explains it quite well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22092971/2136812)

Comment: so just to clarify... i should NOT put it on disk... so then hardcode it into the app itself is acceptable for now?

Comment: put it in the keystore if possible

Comment: thank you Lena, I already have a pre-existing key (and I understand I may need to save the initialization variable (iV) as well... so for now I am trying to put those values into the app.. and for now directly in the source code right as I inject it into an instance of the KeyStore.

I now have another question, which I will post on SO.  Thanks again!

Comment: post the link here, maybe i can help

Comment: I actually got it all working now!  after re-checking my sequence of actions (Base64, Encode/Decode, etc)