# How to store the tensorflow image classification data in the internal storage for android app?

Tags: android, sqlite, tensorflow-lite, android-internal-storage

I have written the code which is integrated with tensoerlow model for image classification but now i want to store that classified data in the database i.e. internal storage.So what can I do for that.
The tensorflow model is flower detection.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're following codelab [Recognize Flowers with TensorFlow Lite on Android](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/recognize-flowers-with-tensorflow-on-android). From [Step 7](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/recognize-flowers-with-tensorflow-on-android#6), you can modify [`recognizeImage`](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/dd98bc2b595157c03ac9fa47ac8659bb20aa8bbd/lite/codelabs/flower_classification/android/finish/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/classification/tflite/Classifier.java#L219) method to export classification result to local file or database. The methods can vary depending on your use case, but for simply exporting to file, you can start from this SO thread.

[Read/Write String from/to a File in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376807/read-write-string-from-to-a-file-in-android)

Comment: Ya I am using Tensorflow flower recognization code,But i want to store the data in the file without any button it should be stored automatically. can you provide me proper code because i dont know which variable data i have to store.

Comment: Do you want to store probabilities, or actual class names?

Comment: I want to store actual class name 1st label with highest perecntage

Comment: Hi @AbhishekRai  Did you save it in the database ? Thanks