# i have a folder inside com.example.myapplication called files inside it there is a file text file called users how to read and write in java

Tags: java, android-studio

i have a folder inside com.example.myapplication called files inside it there is a file text file called users how to read and write in java android studio

i tried bufferread read = new bufferread(new fileread(filename)))

Comment: Check system property user.dir but it should just be `FileReader("com/example/myapplication/files/[filename]")`

Answer (score 1):

### How to read and write to a text file in Android Studio

Here's how you can read and write to a text file called "users" inside the "files" folder of your "com.example.myapplication" project in Android Studio:

**Reading:**

1. Get the file path:

```java
String filename = "users";
File file = new File(getFilesDir(), filename);
```

2. Create a BufferedReader:

```java
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        // Process each line of text
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (reader != null) {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Writing:**

1. Get the file path:

```java
String filename = "users";
File file = new File(getFilesDir(), filename);
```

2. Create a BufferedWriter:

```java
BufferedWriter writer = null;
try {
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    writer.write("This is a line of text");
    writer.newLine();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (writer != null) {
        try {
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:**

The getFilesDir() method gets the directory where your app can store private files.
Use try-with-resources block to automatically close the reader and writer.
You can read and write multiple lines of text using a loop.
Make sure to handle exceptions properly.
Additional resources:

Android developer documentation on file storage: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File
Stack Overflow question on reading and writing to a file: [Read/Write String from/to a File in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376807/read-write-string-from-to-a-file-in-android)

**Regarding your previous attempt:**

The code you provided, bufferread read = new bufferread(new fileread(filename))), is incorrect. It should be:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
```

You misspelled BufferedReader and used fileread instead of FileReader. Remember, class names are case-sensitive in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to read a file:

```
FileInputStream in = openFileInput("filename.txt");
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(in);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
      sb.append(line).append("\n");
}
inputStreamReader.close();
```

This to write to a file instead:

```
String text;
FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput("filename.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
out.write(text.getBytes());
out.close();
```