# How to store simple data in Android with unity?

Tags: android, json, database, unity-game-engine

I am making a clicker-like Android game on Unity and I need to store some data everytime something happens in the game, but it will be very simple data, like some ints and strings. Is it viable to do it serializing it with something like json and store in a file?

Comment: may be you can make use of Preferences (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save data in an android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962344/how-to-save-data-in-an-android-app)

Comment: For your current question, I'll suggest you to store this game related data in sqlite database file (follow the link given by @VividVervet). I don't recommend shared prefs as they can be cleared.

Comment: @Vishal sh I dint get "as they can be cleared"

Comment: If you go to app info and clear data, shared preferences are deleted. That's what happens with my app, I store some registration details in shared prefs in my app, and that restricts the registration dialog popping up. However, when I clear data, data in shared prefs is deleted and popup reappears.

Comment: and do you think database will persist if you clear from the app setting ?

Comment: @Vishal sh you must recheck that information

Comment: The option "Clear Data" will remove the sqlite data as well. But I think, if a User is clicking on that option, then that User is well aware of this fact. 

For your case, you can use SharedPreferences for now. But in case you want to go for complicated/composite data, I would suggest SQLite.

Comment: try [ArrayPrefs2](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/ArrayPrefs2). It may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Mohammed Faizan Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4190853/mohammad-faizan-khan) said, you can use `PlayerPrefs` or `persistentDataPath` to keep and access the data.

A simple example for `PlayerPrefs`:

```
private int score = 0;
private int savedScore;

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.S)) {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score", score);
        Debug.Log(score);
        }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.L)) {
        savedScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score");
        Debug.Log(savedScore);
        }
```

A simple example for `persistentDataPath`:

```
private string savedName;
private int savedHealth;
private string loadedName;
private int loadedHealth;

public void Save(){
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/FileName.dat", FileMode.Create);
    PlayerClass newData = new PlayerClass();
    newData.health = savedHealth;
    newData.name = savedName;
    bf.Serialize(file, newData);
    file.Close();
}

public void Load(){

    if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/FileName.dat")){
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/FileName.dat", FileMode.Open);
        ObjData newData = (ObjData)bf.Deserialize(file);
        file.Close();
        loadedHealth = newData.health;
        loadedName = newData.name;
    }
}

[Serializable]
class PlayerClass{
    public string name;
    public int health;

}
```

Remember that, you need 
`using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;` namespaces for `persistentDataPath`.

Answer (score 1):

Why you want to store it in JSON you can simply use [PlayerPref](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html). If you get any difficulty in getting data from it then, [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/578097/androidsaving-data-with-playerprefs.html) will also help you.

> Stores and accesses player preferences between game sessions.