# android app to - generate sqeuential number and save it

Tags: java, android

I want to make a simple android app to - generate sequential number every time a button is pressed and save it as it is when it is closed. So when I open it next time it starts from there.

In JAVA I got sequential number part figured. But don't know how to save that number upon closing the app.

Just a simple hint could help me find out the rest.

This is my first question here so ignore if you find it too childish.

Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save data in an android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962344/how-to-save-data-in-an-android-app)

Comment: You could use one of the built in simple consistency features: `SharedPreferences` (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it:

1. Using [saveInstanceState()](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/saving-and-retrieving-android-instance-state-part-1/) and [onRestoreInstanceState()](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/saving-and-retrieving-android-instance-state-part-1/) these are the two android activity life cycle methods to store data at the time of closing your app.
2. You can use [SharedPreferences](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm) to save your data. It basically uses a small XML file for storing your data permanently.
3. You can also use [SQLite database](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-sqlite-tutorial) for storing data. [But for this purpose it is not preferable.]

Hope it will meet your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SharedPreference](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) like -

```
    int num = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get your last saved sequential number
        num = getMyNumber();

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ++num;
                saveMyNumber(num);
            }
        });
       ......
     }

    private void saveMyNumber(int num) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putInt("sequencialnum", num);
        editor.commit();
    }

    private int getMyNumber(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPref.getInt("sequencialnum", 0);
    }
```