# How to save items inside an ArrayList when an app is restarted? (Android)

Tags: android

Whenever I restart my app, all the information I saved inside an ArrayList during its runtime is deleted. In addition, sometimes when I go to another activity and then come back from that second activity. The information is deleted again. I'm not sure what's causing this. I want the information to be permanently saved unless deleted by the user. Usually, the error I'm receiving are IndexOutOfBounds exception when I need to call an item from my ArrayList.

Main Activity Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView preset;
    private Button add;
    private ListView exercises;

    private ArrayList<String> exerciseName;
    public ArrayList<Exercise> Exercises;
    private MyAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Exercises = new ArrayList<Exercise>();
        preset = findViewById(R.id.preset_title);
        add = findViewById(R.id.add_exercise);
        exercises = findViewById(R.id.exercises);
        exerciseName = FileHelper.readData(this);
        this.adapter = new MyAdapter(exerciseName, this, Exercises);
        exercises.setAdapter(adapter);
        add.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.add_exercise:
                final int CODE = 1;
                Intent i = new Intent(this, add_activity.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, CODE);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch(requestCode) {
            case 1:
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                    Bundle passBack = data.getExtras();
                    Exercise exercise = passBack.getParcelable("exercise");
                    adapter.addData(exercise);
                    adapter.list.add(exercise.getName());
                    FileHelper.writeData(exerciseName, this);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            case 2:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                    Bundle passBack = data.getExtras();
                    Exercise exercise = passBack.getParcelable("exercise");
                    int position = passBack.getInt("position");
                    adapter.setData(exercise, position);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Custom Adapter Code (where my ArrayList data is stored):

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public ArrayList<String> list;
    private Context context;
    private TextView list_txt;
    private ArrayList<Exercise> data;


    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<String> records, Context context, ArrayList<Exercise> data) {
        super(context, 0, records);
        this.list = records;
        this.data = data;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void addData(Exercise d){
        data.add(d);
    }

    public void setData(Exercise d, int position) {
        data.set(position, d);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listview_custom, parent, false);
        }

        Button list_but = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_but);
        TextView list_txt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById((R.id.list_txt));
        Button edit = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_but2);
        Button start = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_but3);
        list_txt.setText(list.get(position));

        edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final int CODE2 = 2;
                Activity origin = (Activity)context;
                Intent edit = new Intent(parent.getContext(), add_activity.class);
                Bundle newBundle = new Bundle();
                newBundle.putParcelable("exercise", data.get(position));
                newBundle.putInt("position", position);
                edit.putExtras(newBundle);
                origin.startActivityForResult(edit, CODE2);
            }
        });

        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent start = new Intent(parent.getContext(), timer_activity.class);
                start.putExtra("exercise", data.get(position));
                parent.getContext().startActivity(start);
            }
        });
        list_but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alert.setTitle("Delete?");
                alert.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this exercise?");
                alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        list.remove(position);
                        try {
                            data.remove(position);
                        } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {

                        }
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
                alert.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    }
                });
                alert.create().show();
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save data in an android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962344/how-to-save-data-in-an-android-app)

Answer (score 1):

Every time You destroy activity You are losing all saved data in `ListView`. You have to save it before destroying and restore when You start an activity. You can do it with [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) and [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences).

In Your MainActivity override `onSaveInstanceState` and inside this method save all Your exercises from `Exercises` list using `gson`.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();  
String exercisesJSON = gson.toJson(Exercises); 

SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("KEY_BETTER_USE_CONST", exercisesJSON);
editor.commit();
```

And then in `onCreate` restore this data:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String exercisesJSON = sharedPref.getInt("KEY_BETTER_USE_CONST", "DEFAULT_VALUE_EMPTY");

//check if exercisesJSON is equal to "DEFAULT_VALUE_EMPTY" if yes, init array as empty, if not deserialize it using gson

Gson gson = new Gson();  
Exercises[] exercises = gson.fromJson(exercisesJSON, Exercise[].class);
```

Haven't debugged this code but I think it should look something like this. I based on: [Gson — Mapping of Arrays and Lists of Objects](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-mapping-of-arrays-and-lists-of-objects)