# How to store a value

Tags: android, kotlin

So i have a project and want to save a value when the user quits the app and i tried to copy code from the google lemonade project like this:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val LEMONADES = "LEMONADES"
    private val TOTAL_LEMONADES = "TOTAL_LEMONADES"

    private var lemonades = 0
    private var total_lemonades = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            lemonades = savedInstanceState.getInt(LEMONADES, 0)
            total_lemonades = savedInstanceState.getInt(TOTAL_LEMONADES, 0)

            //some code to format the vals
        }
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        outState.putInt(LEMONADES, lemonades)
        outState.putInt(TOTAL_LEMONADES, total_lemonades)
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }
}
```

So am i doing the code wrong or i should use something else?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

Comment: lots and lots of resources available online for how to store values into persistent storage, copying code from another project without having an understanding of what it doesn't isn't going to get you very far

Comment: For user preferences (themes, names, colors, dates and other simple values) you can use `Shared Preferences`. For other (more complex or larger) data, you can either save to a text file into app storage (easier, more primitive with no search and indexing) or a room database (an SQL database).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save data in an android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962344/how-to-save-data-in-an-android-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this for shared references:

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences