# Check if activity is active, and if active pass data from service to activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, service, data-transfer, pass-data

I have a service called `EventReceivingSevice` which will get new data in `onDataRefresh(JSONObject data)` function.

```
private void onNewData(JSONData data) {
    boolean isActive=isActivityActive(); //Check if activity is active
    if(isACtive)
         passData(data);
    else
         storeData(data);
}
```

An activity called `HomeActivity` will display the data. When `EventReceivingService` will get new data, it has to be checked if `HomeActivity` is active, it has to pass the data to `HomeActivity`, and if not it will store the data somewhere so that `HomeActivity` will later use that.

The data is in JSON format.

How can achieve this?

Comment: You can use the [Lifecycle Aware](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle) functionality

Comment: @tomerpacific Do I need to use android.arch (https://www.talentica.com/blogs/android-life-cycle-aware-components/) library as this tutorial suggests.

Comment: I don't know why you went to a tutorial instead of the documentation link I sent. In the documentation itself, there is a link that shows how to add the android.lifecycle dependency. [Link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#declaring_dependencies).

Comment: @tomerpacific Can you please provide an implementation of Lifecycle Aware?

Comment: How large is this data?

Comment: @DavidWasser Less than 50KB

Comment: See my answer. you could write the data to a file, put it in SQLite database, or even keep it in memory in a `public static` variable if you want to. Depends on the level of persistency you need and other factors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reliably determine if an `Activity` is active. What you should do is to store the data somewhere (file, SQLite database, etc.), and then send a broadcast `Intent` that means "new data is available". Your `Activity` can register a listener that will get triggered by that broadcast `Intent` if the `Activity` is alive when the broadcast `Intent` is sent. It can then pick up the data from wherever you put it and do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple method but it doesn't require JSON data. you can just add data as public static data.

```
public static int GRID_COUNT = 2;
```

If you are using that data for reading purposes, you can do it like this.

```
public static final int GRID_COUNT = 2;
```

Comment: But, what about storing data? How will I get to that when I have to store data in file?

Comment: check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962344/how-to-save-data-in-an-android-app). It will help you to find a solution for that.